# Unit testing an C# Azure Durable Function with external events

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-functions, xunit, azure-durable-functions

I've got an Azure Durable Function orchestrator that waits for two external events. Once they've both been received, the orchestrator calls an activity function.

Is there a way to unit test this orchestrator, to verify that the activity function is called only after both events have been received?

Here's the orchestrator function code:

```
[FunctionName("MyOrchestrator")]

public static async Task MyOrchestrator(

    [OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext context)

{
    var event1 = context.WaitForExternalEvent<string>("Event1");
    var event2 = context.WaitForExternalEvent<string>("Event2");
    await Task.WhenAll(event1, event2);

    await context.CallActivityAsync<object>("Activity1", null);
    context.SetOutput(new { Status = "Complete" });
}
```

Comment: Why not just mock `IDurableOrchestrationContext`?

Comment: @StephenCleary Thanks - I just gave that a try with `WaitForExternalEvent` returning `TaskCompletionSource`. Then I'm running the orchestrator in a background task, to prevent blocking the unit test, then I complete the event tasks to unblock the orchestrator and continue on to call the activity. I can then check the call to `CallActivityAsync` was received. The problem is there's a delay between completing the event tasks, and the activity being called, so I need to `Thread.Sleep` between them, which feels a bit kludgy. Can't really think of a better solution though.

Comment: @ChrisFulstow Do not use `Thread.Sleep`. instead await `Task.Delay` with your desired delay and then assert expected behavior.

Comment: @Nkosi good point, it's only a unit test but still better not to block the thread. Ideally though I'd like the remove the need to either.

Comment: @ChrisFulstow it is not needed really once the mock is configured correctly. Check provided answer.

Answer (score 3):

If the mocked context is arranged properly then the activity can only happen after awaiting the two external event tasks to complete.

```
//Arrange
var context = new Mock<IDurableOrchestrationContext>(); //MOQ

context.Setup(_ => _.WaitForExternalEvent<string>(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(async () => {
        await Task.Delay(10); //Delay is optional
        return "";
    });

context.Setup(_ => _.CallActivityAsync<object>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(null);

//Act
await MyFunction.MyOrchestrator(context.Object);

//Assert
context.Verify(_ => _.WaitForExternalEvent<string>("Event1"));
context.Verify(_ => _.WaitForExternalEvent<string>("Event2"));
context.Verify(_ => _.CallActivityAsync<object>("Activity1", null));
context.Verify(_ => _.SetOutput(It.IsAny<object>()));
```

In the above example, using MOQ, the events are setup generically to delay before completing the task. Only then would the activity be invoked.

The test then verifies specific invocations to assert the expected behaviors.

As for how useful this unit test is, not very much, since it is basically testing that framework code awaits as expected.